# Viewing svn diff in apache

Tags: apache, svn, mod-dav-svn

So I just learned that you can view old revisions by adding the "p" parameter as such:

```
http://svn.example.com/repo/?p=123
```

Is it possible to have it display the difference between two revisions? (Similar to svn diff in command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "p" (peg revision) and "r" (operative revision) are described here:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.other
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html

But you can only browse versions - you cannot see "diff's" without additional packages. One good choice is WebSVN:

- http://www.websvn.info/

Check this link for more options:

- [What is the best web based Subversion client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137540/what-is-the-best-web-based-subversion-client)

Comment: Thanks paulsm4. I did notice the "p" and "r" differences earlier on but whenever I use the "r" it automatically gets switched to a "p" instead so I just thought it was obsolete or something. Anyway, those links shed some light to it, although I'm still not 100% sure exactly the difference. As for the question of the topic, thanks for confirming that it's not natively possible. I'll check those third-party solutions out. Thanks!